# Retrieve Timestamps between in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, datetime, timestamp

```
select 
  to_timestamp('2013-06-24 11:36:40 AM', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mi:ss a') >= 
  to_timestamp('2013-06-24 11:20:00 AM', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mi:ss a') 
  and 
  to_timestamp('2013-06-24 11:36:40 AM', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mi:ss a') <= 
  to_timestamp('2013-06-24 11:50:00 AM', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mi:ss a') as a;
```

is true, but:

```
select 
  to_timestamp('2013-06-24 11:36:40 AM', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mi:ss a') >=
  to_timestamp('2013-06-24 11:20:00 AM', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mi:ss a') 
  and 
  to_timestamp('2013-06-24 11:36:40 AM', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mi:ss a') <= 
  to_timestamp('2013-06-24 12:50:00 PM', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mi:ss a') as a
```

result is false

please solve it ..

Comment: "*please solve it*". Please provide a detailed question that can be answered, according to the guidance provided in the new user help here: http://stackoverflow.com/help and the guidance on asking better PostgreSQL questions here: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql/info . What are you trying to accomplish? What result would you *expect* to happen? What did you already try?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use "am" or "pm" not "a" as the 12-hour specifier.

```
to_timestamp('2013-06-24 12:50:00 PM', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mi:ss am')
```

Working this out is a simple process. You get an unexpected "false" from the second query. So you evaluate each branch separately to see which one is false:

```
regress=> select 
regress->   to_timestamp('2013-06-24 11:36:40 AM', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mi:ss a') >=
regress->   to_timestamp('2013-06-24 11:20:00 AM', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mi:ss a');
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)

regress=> select   to_timestamp('2013-06-24 11:36:40 AM', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mi:ss a') <= 
regress->   to_timestamp('2013-06-24 12:50:00 PM', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mi:ss a') as a;
 a 
---
 f
(1 row)
```

OK, so it's the second one that's unexpectedly not matching. The timestamps look like the condition should match, so let's look at the *output* of the `to_timestamp` function on each:

```
regress=> select to_timestamp('2013-06-24 11:36:40 AM', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mi:ss a'), 
  to_timestamp('2013-06-24 12:50:00 PM', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mi:ss a');
      to_timestamp      |      to_timestamp      
------------------------+------------------------
 2013-06-24 11:36:40+08 | 2013-06-24 00:50:00+08
(1 row)
```

Huh, will you look at that. 12:50 has turned into `00:50`. A 12-hour offset suggests that the `PM` isn't being recognised. Let's look at [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE):

- `AM, am, PM or pm`    meridiem indicator (without periods)

Looks like you wanted `am` or `pm`, not just `a` as you wrote in the time pattern you used. Let's try it with the corrected indicator:

```
regress=> select to_timestamp('2013-06-24 12:50:00 PM', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mi:ss am');
       to_timestamp      
------------------------
 2013-06-24 12:50:00+08
(1 row)
```

That did it. Feed it back into the original query and....

```
select 
  to_timestamp('2013-06-24 11:36:40 AM', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mi:ss am') >=
  to_timestamp('2013-06-24 11:20:00 AM', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mi:ss am') 
  and 
  to_timestamp('2013-06-24 11:36:40 AM', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mi:ss am') <= 
  to_timestamp('2013-06-24 12:50:00 PM', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mi:ss am') as a
```

... returns true as expected. So there you go, that's step-by-step problem solving 101.

Comment: @user2493093 Glad to help. I hope you've also got some information that'll help you solve future problems - and come up with better questions when you can't. Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers if this has helped.

Answer (score 1):

I have checked the below query posted by you and found that to_timestamp function returns below result to compare.

**-----Below query returns 0 (i.e.False)-----**

```
select to_timestamp('2013-06-24 11:36:40 AM', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mi:ss a') >= to_timestamp('2013-06-24 11:20:00 AM', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mi:ss a') and to_timestamp('2013-06-24 11:36:40 AM', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mi:ss a') <= to_timestamp('2013-06-24 12:50:00 PM', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mi:ss a')as a
```

**---Below are the conditions for comparison--**
First Condition to compare(this returns True)
 to_timestamp('2013-06-24 11:36:40 AM', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mi:ss a')-->June, 24 2013 10:36:40+0000
 to_timestamp('2013-06-24 11:20:00 AM', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mi:ss a')-->June, 24 2013 10:20:00+0000

**---Second condition to compare(this returns false)--**
 to_timestamp('2013-06-24 11:36:40 AM', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mi:ss a')-->June, 24 2013 10:36:40+0000
 to_timestamp('2013-06-24 12:50:00 PM', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mi:ss a')-->June, 23 2013 23:50:00+0000

As you have noticed that here the second condition compares June, 24 2013 with June, 23 2013 which returns false.

Try Below Query which returns True result

**/---Below query returns 1 (i.e.True)----/**

```
select to_timestamp('2013-06-24 11:36:40 AM', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh24:mi:ss a')
>= to_timestamp('2013-06-24 11:20:00 AM', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh24:mi:ss a') 
and to_timestamp('2013-06-24 11:36:40 AM', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh24:mi:ss a')
<= to_timestamp('2013-06-24 12:50:00 PM', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh24:mi:ss a')as a
```

In above query I have used 24Hr format for comparison.(yyyy-MM-dd hh24:mi:ss)

I have test the result on http://sqlfiddle.com/

I hope this helps you.

Thanks
Jignesh

Comment: The diagnostic process you used is good, but the conclusion is wrong. Using `hh24` won't correctly handle, say, `2:20:00 pm`. You really want the `am` meridiem indicator format placeholder. Upvoting despite that error - thankyou for participating and trying to help others out.